# Changing Query output from Rows to Column in MySQL without interfering with data entries

Tags: mysql, eclipse, gwt

I'm currently having this table called WorkStation5

```
    ID Date Time TemperatureData LightData
```

and I would like plot for example a graph in Eclipse GWT on let say TemperatureData for the past latest 50 entries.

Thus I use this query statement for mySQL.

```
SELECT TemperatureData FROM sensor ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50;
```

However this gives me the records in 1 column and 50 rows datas using this statement 
          while (rs.next()) {
            user = new String[] {rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2)};
          }
It keeps overwriting my data from the client side because I'm not using a table to store my data.

The data which appear when I use the above query statement

```
    TemperatureData
          10
          13
          14
```

latest        43

What I want to achieve is

```
  Temperature Data  10 13 14 43
```

Thus I would like to ask if there is any method to flip this 1 row 50 rows into 1 row by 50 columns without messing up the sequence of the latest entries, 2nd latest.... to 50th entries.

Comment: Are you using DataGrid on GWT side?

Comment: DataGrid meaning? 
I just googled, technically I just require the data to be stored as a variable while using the variable to plot 2D graph using gchart.